# Error while inspecting using Appium

Tags: ios, iphone, appium

I was trying to test my iOS app using Appium.This is the first time am using the app. I got following text in dialogue box. Please help me, thanks in advance.

```
Could not start a new session

Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object.
```

This is the error am getting in console

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPad Retina (8.2 Simulator)', but the available devices were: ["iPad 2 (8.4 Simulator) [69E9798C-BF67-441F-BE0F-BB422C329381]","iPad Air (8.4 Simulator) [10794BA7-C352-4E63-B884-F740E572A626]","iPad Retina (8.4 Simulator) [3C4AE8CC-4EF3-43F0-A2DA-218E1A2021A2]","iPhone 4s (8.4 Simulator) [D54D1665-01A2-4A4E-BA4F-F6F3C74C0B89]","iPhone 5 (8.4 Simulator) [330EDD0C-2B9B-44AE-9F46-3CFE88FB7D6A]","iPhone 5s (8.4 Simulator) [64BDE543-7DFA-448C-A5EE-05A0292A640B]","iPhone 6 (8.4 Simulator) [6A928AA3-2624-429E-AC15-CA2F61483504]","iPhone 6 Plus (8.4 Simulator) [C1F83F38-7846-4C98-97C1-4B663C5D7A8E]"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the device you requested isn't one that is supported. Only ones it  can support according to the error are iOS 8.4

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolved by making the platform version of device in Appium and simulator's version to same. I was using 8.4 simulator while Appium was accepting 8.3.